# False in excel if or statement

Tags: excel

this is my formula, and for the first part if that's results it shows false please

```
=IF(OR(C7=$C$1,D7+$D$1),(IF(C7=$C$2,D7+$D$2)))
```

I tried updating formula to add "" as a blank statement and "d6+d1". one part works and shows the correct result, but if the other option is the one it shows FALSE

Comment: You've got `D7+$D$1` as one of your conditions to `OR` - I believe this will be `TRUE` if `D7 + D1` is anything other than 0: should it be equal to something? Also, you use a similar `D7+$D$2` in the second half, but not as part of an `OR`: should the two halves be doing the same thing? Perhaps you should write out in words what you are trying to get here...

Comment: Define a value for the `FALSE` result too.